# Unable to generate a temporary class

Tags: iis

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS2001: Source
file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\h3ugizgc.0.cs' could not be found error CS2008:
No inputs specified

error line
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xmlSettings));
Line 52:                 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Items));
Line 53:                 items = (Items)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

I am getting this error message when I try to rum my application using IIS on Windows 7.

Answer (score 8):

Is your application configured to run under a specific user account?

If so, check the user account associated to the application has List Folder Contents and Read permissions on the %windir%\Temp folder.

Comment: I ran into this and although my IIS was "out of the box" I still needed to add IIS_IUSRS before things would work.

Comment: I also run into this when updating an azure cloud service from SDK 1.7 to SDK 1.8. Allowing the user NETWORKSERVICE (here in german NETZWERKDIENST) access to c:\windows\temp: list folder contents and read. And everything works fine in compute emulator.
I also use IIS and win7

Comment: I really don't like this.  I am installing my application on a users machine.  I don't want to have to alter their folder permissions to "make" it work.  InstallShield can most likely do this, but I would be changing the default behavior (Windows Server 2008 in my case).  This is not an IIS issue for me but it is the exact same problem.  Does anyone know the actual cause so I can come up with something from a coding perspective?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it's still valid (and the issue still happens), and here's more information in case anyone else runs into this: http://blog.coderunnr.com/2012/06/net-xmlserializer-unable-to-generate-a-temporary-class/.

The post includes a couple of solutions (adding an attribute to the schema) with examples. The problem is actually a bug in .NET's XmlSerializer: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/349967/xsd-exe-generates-code-with-the-wrong-type-in-an-xmlarrayitemattribute

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you make the user a local administrator

- Open Computer management og Right-clik "Computer" and choose manage.
- Expand: Groups
- Double-click: Administrator group
- Add user to group

Hope this works.